# How can I auto-rename long string values to more readable strings?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Essentially, I have a data set that is mostly made up of columns populated with long hashes, but for ease of reading and reporting, I would like to rename these hashes to val_1, val_2, val_3, etc...

For one of the columns, there are only 10 values so using rename.values works fine *e.g.*

```
rename.values(x,hash='val_1')
```

but one of the columns has over 500 unique values, so going through and doing that by hand is impractical. Is there a way to categorize these hashes automatically?

I imagine there is a way to do this with a for loop but it's evading me.

Comment: It would help to see some example data, in a plain-text format, and an example of desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forcats package has a function to do that.  If `x` is the column of interest convert it to a factor, anonymize the levels using `fct_anon` and then optionally `format` it to turn back into a character column.  Omit `format` if it is ok to keep it as a factor.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
data <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c")) # test input

data %>% mutate(x = format(fct_anon(as_factor(x), "val_")))
```

Another possibility not using forcats is:

```
data %>%  mutate(x = sprintf("val_%d", factor(x)))
```

Comment: Oh that's beautiful, so much simpler than what I was trying to do. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a little bit, but I think

```r
hash_vals <- c("aaaa","aaaa","bbbbc","ddeef","bbbbc")
uu <- unique(hash_vals)
new_labs <- paste0("val_",seq(length(uu)))
new_vals <- new_labs[match(hash_vals,uu)]
## [1] "val_1" "val_1" "val_2" "val_3" "val_2"
```

should work?

This is not in tidyverse.  Obviously you could use `mutate()` to create the `new_vals` variable, although I can't easily think of a way to do the `new_labs`/`new_vals` computations on the fly in a way that's readable and efficient ...

You could create a new data frame and then join, i.e. (untested!)

```r
mtab <- old_dat %>%
    select(hash_vals) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    mutate(new_vals=paste0("vals_",seq(n()))
full_join(old_dat,mtab, by="hash_vals") %>% select(-hash_vals)
```

Another base-R possibility is

```r
new_vals <- factor(hash_vals, levels=unique(hash_vals),
                    labels=paste0("val_",seq(length(unique(hash_vals)))
```

(and then convert back to character if you want)

Comment: Oooooh that's clever.... I'll have to make a few small edits to the first answer but that is 100% what I needed, thank you!